# Concurrency and Java Synchronization

Tags: java, multithreading

Consider the following code:

```
public class MyObject{

    synchronized void f() {
        System.out.print("a ");
        System.out.print("b ");
    }

    synchronized void g() {
        System.out.print("z ");
        System.out.print("x ");
    }

    void h() {
        System.out.print("1 ");
        System.out.print("2 ");
    }
}
```

Thread 1 class

```
public class Thread1 implements Runnable {
    MyObect myObject;

    Thread1(MyObject t){
        MyObject = t;
    }

    public void run() {
        myObject.f();
    }
}
```

Thread 2 class

```
public class Thread2 implements Runnable {
    MyObect myObject;

    Thread2(MyObject t) {
        myObject = t;
    }

    public void run() {
        myObject.g();
        myObject.g();
    }
}
```

Main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyObject myObj = new MyObject();
    Thread1 t1 = new Thread(new Thread1(myObj));
    Thread1 t2 = new Thread(new Thread1(myObj));
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
}
```

When you run the main class, would all the possible outputs be

- a b z x z x
- z x z x a b

Or can Thread2 sleep in the middle which would result in something like

z x a b z x

Comment: all three outcomes are legal

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can sleep in the middle so all three are possible because it releases the lock after each call to `g`. Otherwise those methods are synchronized and guaranteed to run in their entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to get something like zxabzx because you release the lock and require it in Thread 2

Answer (score 0):

> can Thread2 sleep in the middle ?

Yes, it can, Thread 2 will have to release lock on `MyObect` as soon as execution of first `g()` completes. 
So, It can allow other thread to take lock on `MyObect` before proceeding with the next `g()`

Answer (score 0):

Remember that a Thread can always yield the processor (CPU/GPU) to another thread in the middle of its execution which is something very common when the thread executes for a long period of time ("long" meaning a couple of milliseconds)